# Config files for libraries on linux?

Tags: linux, configuration, shared-libraries, driver

I have created a library which reads/writes from a can bus and converts the data in a special format for an application.

Now I want to configure that library with parameters like CanBus nb. baudrate and so on.

Can I use a config.ini file for that? And if yes, where do I have to put it on the filesystem(linux)? Is there a special place for it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux the **/etc** directory is used for configuration files by convention. You might want to consider that. Here is a document for further study http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/etc.html.

Read it, it may help you make the decision